# Creating service in SLES / SUSE 11 SP3

Tags: shell-script, services, init.d, sles

I have a python script that works very well executed from a (remote) console like this :

```
sudo /srv/web-asset-server-master/python server.py
```

The problem is, that it only lives as long as the console window is open. So I want to run it as a service, but this seems to be more tricky that I thought. Have followed this recipe -> **https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html** (and read similar questions here on Unix & Linux like [**How to run my script after SuSE finished booting up?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43230/87942)

By following all the fundamentals in the above mentioned [**Creating Custom init Scripts**](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html) I have made this :

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# Copyright (c) 2015 NHMD / specify
# All rights reserved.
#
# Author: Ben Anhalt, 2015
#
# /etc/init.d/attachment-server
#   and its symbolic link
# /usr/sbin/attachment-server

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          attachment-server
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     3 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: Specify attachment server
# Description:       The attachment server is storage medie for Specify attachments 
#       service.  We want it to be active in runlevels 3
#       and 5, as these are the runlevels with the network
#       available.
### END INIT INFO

# Check for missing binaries
ATT_BIN=/srv/web-asset-server-master/python server.py
test -x $ATT_BIN || { echo "$ATT_BIN not installed";
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 5; fi; }

# Load the rc.status script for this service.
. /etc/rc.status

# Reset status of this service
rc_reset

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting attachment server "
        ## Start daemon with startproc(8). If this fails
        ## the return value is set appropriately by startproc.
        startproc $ATT_BIN

        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down attachment server "
        ## Stop daemon with killproc(8) and if this fails
        ## killproc sets the return value according to LSB.

        killproc -TERM $ATT_BIN

        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
   restart)
        ## Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
        ## running or not, start it again.
        $0 stop
        $0 start

        # Remember status and be quiet
        rc_status
        ;;
    reload)
        # If it supports signaling:
        echo -n "Reload service attachment server "
        killproc -HUP $ATT_BIN
        #touch /var/run/BAR.pid
        rc_status -v

        ## Otherwise if it does not support reload:
        #rc_failed 3
        #rc_status -v
        ;;
    status)
        echo -n "Checking for service attachment-server "
        ## Check status with checkproc(8), if process is running
        ## checkproc will return with exit status 0.

        # Return value is slightly different for the status command:
        # 0 - service up and running
        # 1 - service dead, but /var/run/  pid  file exists
        # 2 - service dead, but /var/lock/ lock file exists
        # 3 - service not running (unused)
        # 4 - service status unknown :-(
        # 5--199 reserved (5--99 LSB, 100--149 distro, 150--199 appl.)

        # NOTE: checkproc returns LSB compliant status values.
        checkproc $ATT_BIN
        # NOTE: rc_status knows that we called this init script with
        # "status" option and adapts its messages accordingly.
        rc_status -v
        ;;
    *)
        ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

rc_exit
```

It is the most simple example with the service name and script path changed. And the "attachment-server" *is* now actually registered by YAST in System -> System Services, but when I try to enable it I get the error

> /etc/init.d/attachment-server start returned 2 (invalid or excess
>   arguments)

What could possible be wrong? I cannot figure out where this script should be wrong. It basically just need to execute a single script, thats it.

Must say I am completely novice on SLES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
ATT_BIN=/srv/web-asset-server-master/python server.py
```

is setting variable ATT_BIN and then executing server.py. Normally, ATT_BIN should be a the full pathname to a single file to execute, for example `/home/me/server.py`, if that is where your python script is.

Usually, server.py is changed so that the first line is, in your case:

```
#!/srv/web-asset-server-master/python
```

Then you dont need to specify the interpreter when you run it, and can just set

```
ATT_BIN=/home/me/server.py
```

Make sure you set the executable permissions on your python file, eg:

```
chmod a+rx /home/me/server.py
```