# How to configure firewall on OpenSuse (Leap) to set up NAT redirection?

Tags: iptables, opensuse, firewall, suse

I need to set up a firewall configuration rule so any requests sent to a specific port for a specific destination address get (transparently to the connecting application) redirected to a specific port on the same machine. I know the `iptables` command for this and I have set it up to work with FirewallD on other systems before.

The trouble is that this time I need to set it up on OpenSuse (Leap). I am able to run my `iptables` command and have verified that the command works. The problem, of course, is that the setting is not persistent and is lost upon reboot.

I have learned that OpenSuse uses something called `SuseFirewall2` and that it allows setting up custom `iptables` rules by adding them to the `/etc/sysconfig/scripts/SuSEfirewall2-custom` file inside some functions. I have tried that and it doesn't seem to have any effect. I have also ensured that the `FW_CUSTOMRULES` setting in both `/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2` and `/sbin/SuSEfirewall2` is set to `/etc/sysconfig/scripts/SuSEfirewall2-custom`.

I haven't found much useful information on the web and am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Is there something obvious that I am missing? Any suggestions as to what I should try are welcome too.

Ideally I would like to solve this within the `SuseFirewall2` setup and not throw it out completely and replace with pure `iptables` scripts.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I see that [OpenSuse](https://en.opensuse.org/Firewalld) also has the [Firewalld](http://www.firewalld.org/) software. The advantage would be that it's available on other distributions too, for example [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld), [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls), [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/firewalld/) and [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firewalld).

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

I had missed this critical detail - you want to redirect *to the same machine*. **SuSEFirewall2 doesn't really support this**.

So you either create an aliased interface, and redirect from your real interface to the alias; or you put your existing `iptables` rules into the appropriate script.

This might be `/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/firewall` in the "net-reconfig-done" section:

```
           net-reconfig-done)
                    [ "$FIREWALL" = 'yes' ] || exit 2
                    sfw2_active || exit 3
                    /sbin/SuSEfirewall2 --bootunlock start

                    /usr/sbin/iptables ...YOUR_RULES...
```

but you risk it being overwritten at the next upgrade. Or you prepare a custom executable start script in init.d (you can copy from one of the existing ones), assuming that you are in runlevel 5

```
# runlevel
5
```

then you will use rc5.d and create the script in

```
/etc/init.d/rc5.d/S55Redirector
```

The key part of the script would be:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Applying redirect rules"
        /usr/sbin/iptables ...YOUR_RULES...
        /usr/sbin/iptables ...YOUR_RULES...
        /usr/sbin/iptables ...YOUR_RULES...
        rc_status -v
        ;;
```

## OLD ANSWER

The fastest way to be sure that this is working is set it up from `yast`.

From the root shell:

```
yast
```

from the menu on the left, choose "Security"; from the one on the right, "Firewall".
[image]

In the "allowed services", add the services you need to have them accepted.

[image]

Depending on exact SuSE version, go down to "Masquerading". There you should be able to specify destination host as well as destination port.

As luck would have it, <s>my only LEAP machine</s>my only other LEAP machine is at home, currently down, and the other is not a firewall, so I can't verify or supply a third screenshot.

I suspect that you got the Custom rules right, but forgot to allow the incoming packets in the config file (it should go in `/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2.d/services`). If it doesn't work, you can get back to me (lserni@gmail.com) after Thursday when I'll be back home.

Comment: The Masquerading options are disabled for me as it says "Masquerading needs atleast one external interface and one other interface". Not sure what that means.

Comment: Assuming as you suspect that I forgot to allow the incoming packets in the config file, how do I do that?

Comment: I am, as usual, a dimwit. Corrected answer, and accept my apologies (oh, you *still* need to accept the incoming packets for the externally visible ports in the "Allowed Services" section of the firewall)

Comment: I went ahead and implemented the `/etc/init.d/rc5.d/S55Redirector` script as you suggested. Restarted the machine and my `iptables` rules were not automatically applied. I am not sure if that script actually ran at all. How do I debug this?

Comment: You can first verify whether the script runs correctly by starting it manually with 'start' as first argument. Inside the script you can write to /var/log/messages with `echo "Message" | logger -t myfirewall`.

Comment: Just ran it manually and it said that it needs to be run as root so I ran it with `sudo`. That applied my rules and produced the output `rc_status: command not found`. Is the `rc_status` even needed, as it did successfully apply my rules? So, the script seems fine (enough?), how do I check whether/why doesn't the script run at start up?

Comment: There is a rc include at the beginning of S scripts (you can find it in any other S script). To see when and how it runs, you set a logger inside the script as describe above, then you can check `/var/log/messages`. Verify that you are indeed now in runlevel 5 by running the command `runlevel`.

Comment: Got the `rc_status` thing resolved by copying the `include`. Now, there's no `/var/log/messages` file. I manually ran `echo "Message" | logger -t myfirewall` but that didn't create it either.

Comment: I ended up adding my `iptables` command to `/etc/init.d/after.local` as descried @ https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43255/162588.